# Azure Data Pipeline Copy Activity loses column names when copying from SAP Hana to Data Lake Store

Tags: azure, hana, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am trying to copy data from SAP Hana to Azure Data Lake Store (DLS) using a Copy Activity in a Data Pipeline via Azure Data Factory.

Our copy activity runs fine and we can see that rows made it from Hana to the DLS, but they don't appear to have column names (instead they are just given 0-indexed numbers).

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-create-datasets#Structure) says *“For structured data sources, specify the structure section only if you want map source columns to sink columns, **and their names are not the same**.”*

We are fine using the original column names from the SAP Hana table, so it seems like we shouldn't need to specify the `structure` section in our dataset. However, even when we do, we still just see numbers for column names.

We have also seen the `translator` property at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-map-columns#sample-2--column-mapping-with-sql-query-from-azure-sql-to-azure-blob), but are not sure if that is the route we need to go.

Can anyone tell me why we aren't seeing the original column names copied into DLS and how we can change that? Thank you!

## UPDATE

Setting the `firstRowAsHeader` property of the `format` section on our dataset to `true` basically solved the problem. The console still shows the numerical indices, but now includes the headers we are after as the first row. Upon downloading and opening the file, we can see the numbers are not there (the console just shows them for whatever reason), and it is a standard comma-delimeted file with a header row and one row entry per line.

#### Example:

`COLUMNA,COLUMNB
aVal1,bVal1
aVal2,bVal2`

We can now tell our sources and sinks to write and expect this format when reading.

## BONUS UPDATE:

To get rid of the numerical indices and see the proper column headers in the console, click ***Format*** in the top-left corner, and then check the "***First row is a header***" box toward the bottom of the resulting blade

Comment: Nice knowledge sharing

Answer (score 0):

See the update above.

The `format.firstRowAsHeader` property needed to be set to `true`